# Safari version iOS simulators

Tags: safari, ios-simulator

Hi i'm developping an ionic 3 app and i'd like to know the version of Safari used in iOS simulators, anyone know how to get it ?

Comment: Just in case anyone was wondering: The version of Safari (and everything else) in the Simulator is the same as the one that ships with the relevant OS on device, just built for the simulator architecture. So the iOS 10.3 Simulator runs the same Safari as iOS 10.3 does on your iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to know the user agent string?  You can grab it by visiting one of many sites, eg: http://www.whatsmyua.info?

Answer (score 0):

There's a great listing of Safari user agents at:

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/safari/

You can sort by version number, operating syste (OS X/iPad/iPhone etc)

iPhone simulator user agents will have the `iPhone Simulator` fragment in them, for example:

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/18845-safari-ios-iphone-webkit

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3`